# H Bridge MOSFETs burns after a few seconds

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

i've this circuit, the inpust H1, H2, L1, L2, VS1 and VS2 are unconnected (are the outputs of the mosfet driver) only i power-up with 12V, I only connect the 12V, after a few seconds the mosfet catches fire, the problem is in the schematic or in the pcb making?
BTW: 12v come from a car battery
[image]

Comment: You can't leave the gates floating. The FET's might turn on and shoot trough.

Comment: but that can burn the mosfets?

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro - yes. The gates need to be shorted to their own source terminal to ensure they don't conduct.

Answer (score 2):

> the inpust H1, H2, L1, L2, VS1 and VS2 are unconnected

*but that can burn the mosfets?*

**YES.**

A floating gate means that there is a high chance that the MOSFETs are **neither fully on nor fully off**.

They are probably "somewhere in the middle" meaning that they act like resistors. So current can flow and the MOSFETs **heat up** and destroy themselves.

NEVER leave the gate of a MOSFET floating. In a **properly designed circuit** there would be resistors between the gate and source of each MOSFET, that will make Vgs = 0 and turn the MOSFET off. Four 100 kohm resistors will do the job.

As an experiment, make this circuit and see if you can power the circuit and make the LED **not** light up:

[image: schematic]

Then add a 100 kohm resistor between the gate and Ground and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I have a question. I thought large MOS devices require a substantial amount of gate charge to charge up the gate-oxide-channel capacitor as well as the overlap capacitances (CGS, CGD, etc.). Wouldn't that be very hard to get from a parasitic caps, hence make it difficult to turn on a FET with a floating gate.

Comment: The charge can accumulate, so given enough time the mosfet will start conducting. I’d suggest you get yourself a mosfet and start experimenting.

Comment: Yep, once the charge is there and can't go anywhere, it will stay there. And *a substantial amount of gate* is relative, build the circuit I suggested and see if you can get that "substantial" amount of charge in the gate to make the LED light up just bij touching the gate with your finger.

Answer (score 0):

> H1, H2, L1, L2, VS1 and VS2 are unconnected

H1, H2, L1 and L2 are the MOSFET Gates. The Gate of a MOSFET is well insulated from the channel and so even a small amount of static electricity can charge it up enough to turn the FET on. If the upper and lower FETs on the same side of the bridge turn on at the same time then a current will 'shoot through' both FETs, limited only by the FET on-resistance and power supply current limiting. This can quickly destroy them.

You should wire a resistor (eg. 10 kΩ) between each FET's Gate and Source to make sure it stays turned off when not connected to a driver.